# How to use the ASP.NET Regular expression validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set the minimum number of characters for a textbox, and if the user input dos not reach the set minimum an error must show, In i was trying to do just that using `<asp:RegularExperssionValidator>` but the error message is nit showing, what am i missing or doing wrong?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="ID length is Less than 10" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationExpression=".{10}.*">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

```
                `
```

Comment: Add ^ and $ characters and try it like this "^[.]{10}$"
Also Display="Static" or Dynamic if you don't use ajax callout extenders

Comment: Try this `/.{10,}/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="ID length is Less than 10" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,1000}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
  <br />
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: try this @SibusisoShongwe

Comment: I assume this is the Range {10,1000}